# Is it possible to use routerLink with full link?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When I use [routerLink] it only generates the link after # in the page code.

```
href = "#/category/page"
```

Would it be possible to generate the link completely?

```
href = "http://example.com/#/category/page"
```

I'm having trouble generating sitemaps with the link incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

[No, it appears not.](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

`Router` deals with *application routes*, not URLs, and doesn't know anything about the part of your path before the `#`.

If you'd like to test that, in any component (say, your main AppComponent), add this to your constructor

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {}
```

and then

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.dir(this._router);
}
```

You will see that the `Router` doesn't contain any reference to anything above the application's root route, which it considers `/`.

EDIT: you may wish to look into [`PathLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy), but the implementation is non-trivial.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to include #,cut means nothing. The previous paths are automatically prepended to your current link.

Whether it's **href** or **routerLink** with brackets or without, it doesn't change a thing.

It completely depends on the file in which you have the link. If you want to refer to the files inside of your current directory in which you're file exists. You need to give path in nested order like directory name then file name or if you have more nested directories you need to give path accordingly.

I you're referring to files a level up to your current file directory, you can add ../ for one directory back or ../.. for two and so on.

Comment: _"Whether it's href or routerLink with brackets or without, it doesn't change a thing"._ Actually, it does. For example, if your application is not hosted at the domain root, using `<a href="/">` and `<a [routerLink]="/">` will do *fundamentally different things.* The `#` is also far from meaningless.